# Why am i not able to import import com.itsmypac.librarymanagementsystem.databinding.ActivityMainBinding;?

Tags: android, android-studio, import

Hi I am not able to import this
I am getting error on the .databinding

```
import com.itsmypac.librarymanagementsystem.databinding.ActivityMainBinding;
```

The error is

```
Cannot resolve symbol 'databinding'
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add this codes in your build.grandle.

```
android {
    ...
    dataBinding{
        enabled=true
    }
}
```

Comment: Nope It is still getting the same problem @BlackEgg